# What are the penalties for leaving the game or surrendering?

Tags: league-of-legends

When leaving a game, either by a majority of surrender votes, or leaving at champion selection (queue-dodging), is there some sort of penalty, like less ip or an "autoreport"?

If you leave in champion selection, are there any penalties beside the wait time? I know that voting for surrender in a ranked penalizes you, but for how much???

Comment: I don't feel confident enough in this to post as a full answer, but I believe the following happens. 1) You recieve zero IP 2) The game is counted as a loss for matchmaking/LP purposes, even if your team wins 3)Too many leaves leads to a ban.

Comment: Also, voting for a surrender in ranked doesn't penalize you, except that it counts as a loss, although if you're surrendering you probably consider the loss inevitable anyway.

Comment: I swear that there is a question like this one. but I can't find it.

Comment: I do know that both teams, if the losing team surrenders, will earn less IP/exp as the amount rewarded is based off of win/loss AND the amount of time it takes to complete the match. So in shorter games you will earn less of both, regardless of if was a surrender or they were able to kill your nexus.

Answer (score 13):

All leaves are automatically handled by the `LeaverBuster`. Leaver Buster is an automated system that Riot implemented to discourage players from leaving League of Legends matches.

**Leaving the game during champion selection:**

You will receive a punishment (if it wasn't a custom match). On the first offense, you will be unable to join the matchmaking queue for 6 minutes.
For the second and following offenses, you will be unable to join the matchmaking queue for 15 minutes.

In addition to the above time penalties, if the game was a ranked match, you will lose 3 League Points for the first offense and 10LP for the second time before the timer reset.

This timer resets after 8 hours without leaving during champion select and is shared between normal and ranked games.

**Leaving the game before the match is over:**

A player can leave the game before the match is over. In addition to that, the Leaver Buster system will automatically kick players who remain idle for 5 minutes.

When you leave a game, you will gain no XP/IP for the abandoned game. The match will show up as a `leave` in your profile and a `loss` is added to your statistics, even if your team wins.

If a game doesn't end (for example for server issues, or because every player left the match), no penalties are given out.

After receiving a certain number of leaves, which varies depending on the total number of games played and the distance in time between each leave, the player account gets first warned and then suspended for increasingly long periods of time, resulting in a permanent ban for re-iterated offenses.

If the majority of the team votes to surrender and  the game ends that way, then it's a fair ending of the match. Of course, you will have lost the match and lose LP if it's a ranked game, but it's not considered a leave. You will receive IP and XP for the match.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is taken straight from the League of legends wikia: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Leaver_Buster

**Leaver Buster** is an automated system that Riot implemented to discourage players from leaving League of Legends matches.

Leaving the game during champion selection:

**Punishment (normal match):**
1st offense - Player is unable to join the matchmaking queue for 6 minutes.
2nd and following offenses - Player is unable to join the matchmaking queue for 15 minutes.3 points
In addition to the above time penalties if the game was a ranked match, the player loses 3 League Points, for the first offense and 10LP for the second time before the timer reset.
This counter resets after 8 hours without leaving during champion select.
This counter is shared between normal and ranked.

**Leaving the game before the match is over:**
The Leaver Buster system will automatically kick players who remain idle for 5 minutes.
Punishment (All): No XP/IP granted for the abandoned game
Punishment (Normal Match): A leave is added to the player's profile.
Punishment (Ranked Match): A loss is added to the player's profile. (Even if the players team wins)

If a game doesn't end (for example for server issues, or because every player left the match), no penalties are given out.

After receiving a certain number of leaves, which varies depending on the total number of games played and the distance in time between each leave, the player account gets first warned and then suspended for increasingly long periods of time, resulting in a permanent ban for re-iterated offenses.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen 2 of my friends lose [honor ribbons](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/honor) by leaving multiple games during champion select.  Their honor values on their profile stayed intact so it was not the same as a ban or "autoreport" as you mentioned.  The only notable difference was that they lost their ribbons.

Another penalization of sorts is the wait time to re-enter the team select queue.  If you leave champion select before the timer ticks down to 10 seconds, there is a 5 minute wait before you can search for another team to play with.  If you leave with under 10 seconds to go **or** after you have locked in your champion, the wait will be increased to 15 minutes.

*Note the source of all the above information is purely from my own experience, I do not have a linked source for this information, if anyone finds a linked source please edit this post and add in the link

Comment: I must say I've left the game before in the last 3 seconds of champion select. In those occassions, I got a 5 minute penalty as well instead of 15. The time is based on how many times you have left before.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 obvious facts about teamplay

1) every teammate can have problem
the reason can be different  hardware/software/light/personal issues

2) if 1 or 2 players do not wanna or cannot play
You will lose anyway

The truth is that server cannot know reasons of 
bad behavior of player.

I think ability to block player is more then enough.
I read the nickname and 
whenever I want I add it blocklist.
I can do that during champ selection, after game end.

So we have 2 possibilities here:
afk or bad player 
1) during champion selection
2) during game

so
1) we should able to quit champ selection without punishment.
(remember if You quit with no reason 
teammates can block You)
2) surrender system
after 10 minutes - 4 players required to vote yes
after 15 minutes - 3 players required to vote yes

Nothing will help You if your teammate is afk or playing bad.
The truth that You can open score at 10 minutes
and see You have chances to win or not (if score 15 0 - no way).

If You surrendered without reason
Your teammates or enemies can block You
and You will never able to play with them.